# Dragging-and-dropping an image from an application to the browser is not anymore possible with the new dialog box

Tags: bug, status-declined, images

I was used to drap-and-drop the screenshots I wanted to add to my posts directly from the application I use to take them, but it is not anymore possible with the new dialog box.

[image: screenshot]

I can only drag the image to the dialog box once I dropped it on the desktop.

I am using Google Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Mac OS X 10.8.2.
It doesn't seem a problem with the broswer, since dragging the image from the screenshot application to the address bar of Google Chrome works, and I am able to see the image from the browser.

This is only a problem with Google Chrome. I tried with Safari 6.0.2 running on the same computer, and drag-and-drop works.

Comment: I was going to complain about the very same thing. Dragging to `Choose File` used to work, now it doesn't.

Comment: Well, I personally would like to voice my complaint about the "No file chosen" text not being vertically centered.

Comment: I would like to see the ability to directly *copy & paste* images like http://discourse.org has

Comment: @Pekka웃 - You can copy and paste with Chrome.

Comment: @Oded wow, indeed! Coool.

Comment: @Oded do we have you to thank for that? Nice. Is this new? It would deserve a meta announcement IMO

Comment: @Pekka웃 - [Jeremy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202998/jeremy-tunnell) came up with the requirement, the implementation is mine. Didn't implement paste in other browsers as it is would involve a few nasty hacks. The paste and drag/drop are new.

Comment: @animuson - Noted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - You can drop anywhere in the dialog.

Comment: @Oded: except that it doesn't work. I use Skitch to make screenshots, which has a drag area. I used to be able to drag that and drop it on the `Choose File` button in Chrome. Now the drop *always* fails, anywhere in that dialog box (including the file button).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Something for me to test for then. Will try to fit it early next week.

Comment: @Oded: The paste option is a good work-around for now, actually, that works fine for Skitch.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is what I do as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters & kiamlaluno - glad you have a workaround for now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Are you also using a Mac? I tried Skitch for Windows and couldn't repro.

Comment: @Oded: Yup, I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as this is only affecting a small number of users and that there is an easy work around (use paste) and we will not be fixing this bug.